# Bootstrap- Change grids based on orientation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to create a page which would display in two columns in landscape mode but switch to one column in portrait mode. Below is what I wish for:
**Landscape:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">image goes here</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">text goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Portrait:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            image goes here
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            text goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I achieve this using Bootstrap?

Comment: You can try col-md-6 (or col-sm-6) and col-xs-12, maybe works

Comment: The question is how would it change each time the orientation changes?

Answer (score 0):

If the bootstrap columns not works, you can use media

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … } // Define width 100%

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … } // Define width 50%